# Localization with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, hindi

Just say I am to make a news portal in a local language for example in language `Hindi`. How do I prepare the content to be displayed on the website? I guess I have the following ways:

1) Type the data using a `Hindi` keyboard.
2) Add a new language in the control panel and use the regular keyboard and type in you content.

Am I right? I guess I need to set the font as `Unicode`? So why is there a `hindi` (devanagiri) font in the fonts folder (it can be seen when you drop the fonts list down on MS Word.).

Also if my ASP.NET web app requires end users to type in hindi? What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Localization is a process of customizing an existing application for specific cultures or regions. Your application does not exist yet and you need to perform its [globalization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6270d0z(v=vs.110).aspx).

There are some best practices common to all

- use unicode for all your pages (i.e. `<meta charset="utf-8" />`)
- use unicode in database (nvarchar, ntext, etc)

Entering information is not an asp.net question. If your users have no hindi keyboard they could use a virtual keyboard.